# How do you transpose rows into columns in r?

Tags: r, transpose

I have this table:

```
ID        Day          Score
23928     Monday       75
394838    Tuesday      83
230902    Wednesday    90
329832    Thursday     40
…
```

and goes on, repeating day several times.

I want to transpose the day column to get this table

```
MONDAY   Tuesday    Wednesday …… Sunday
78        4343           343      433
```

Is there a way to do this in r ?

Comment: Your output doesn't match your input...

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table::transpose`

```
library(data.table)
data.table::transpose(df1[-1], make.names = 'Day')
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
as.data.frame.list(with(df1, setNames(Score, Day)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(23928L, 394838L, 230902L, 329832L),
Day = c("Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"), Score = c(75L, 83L, 90L, 
40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is stored in a data.frame, you could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
df %>% 
  select(-ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Day, values_from=Score)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday
   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     75      83        90       40
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `t` and set names:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(df$Score)), df$Day)
```

Output

```
#   Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday
#     75      83        90       40
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
data <- data.frame(day = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"),
                   val = c(12,75,9,38)    )
data %>% spread(day,val)
```

Result:

```
   Monday Thursday Tuesday Wednesday
      12       38      75         9
```